# Java Code to convert seconds into minutes, hours and days

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java code that asks the user to insert a number of seconds they would like to convert, how ever i can't get it to work.
Can some one help??
Code Below
...................................

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Week2Seconds {


    private static final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
    private static final int SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog");

        String seconds   = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter Number Of Seconds to Convert");

    }

  private static String timeConversion(int seconds) {

        final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
        final int SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;

        int minutes = seconds / SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;
        seconds -= minutes * SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;

        int hours = minutes / MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;
        minutes -= hours * MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;

        return hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
    }
}
```

Many Thanks
Vinnie

Comment: _how ever i can't get it to work._ Why not?

Comment: I assume you're having issues with getting a `String` to a `int`?  In which case you could use `Integer.parseInt`.  Also Java 8's `Duration` class would be reasonably helpful here

Comment: How would i go about that, im new to Java coding and dont fully understand it

Comment: When i compile and run it, it shows up the box to ask the user in input a number then it just stops working, like its loading

Comment: Well that's all your code does. You display a JOptionPane and then stop processing. You never invoke your method to do the conversion.

Comment: how would i go about invoking it?

Comment: You mean you haven't learned how to invoke methods yet in your class? Check your notes.

Comment: hint: you need to invoke `timeConversion(int seconds)`, passing it the number your user input, to get it's highly desirable `return` parameter.

Comment: Haha I've never seen anyone tell and OP that the answer is wrong when they've probably tested it.

Answer (score 3):

You have your `seconds` stored as a `String`, the computer doesnt know that the input is a number and heck it might not even be a number. You can use the static method `Integer.parseInt` to attempt to convert the string to an integer.

```
int numSeconds = Integer.parseInt(seconds)
```

This can throw a `NumberFormatException` if `seconds` is not a valid number.

Once you have the number as the correct type you can pass this to your method `timeConversion(numSeconds);`

---

As per your comment on why your program isnt exiting correctly because you created a `JFrame`, the `JFrame` will keep your program running until it is properly disposed of. Using the `JFrame` class is outside the scope of your question, however your program you dont need this frame at all, remove it. Pass `null` as the `parentComponent` for the `showInputDialog` method.

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number Of Seconds to Convert");`

---

Some followup questions you might have could be:

- *How do I handle cases where the number is invalid?* - Use a `try { } catch(NumberFormatException e) { }` and act accordingly. This SO question and awnser should help you [JAVA Input Validation for Number Range and Numeric values only with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277619/java-input-validation-for-number-range-and-numeric-values-only-with-counter)
- *How do I keep looping until the user inputs a correct number?* - In combination with the first bullet point and the related SO question, in addition this SO question should help. [How can I check for invalid input and loop until the input is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713609/how-can-i-check-for-invalid-input-and-loop-until-the-input-is-valid)